# How to reshape 'year' from a single feature?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have a df containing columns 'year' and 'per capita income (US$)'.

```
plt.scatter(df.year, df['per capita income (US$)'], color='red')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Per Capita Income (US$)')
plt.show()

reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df[['year']], df['per capita income (US$)'])

reg.predict(2011)
```

Error message received:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=2011.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I adjusted the call of reg.predict() to:

```
reg.predict([[2011]])
```

Code executed without error, however, the `.predict()` function didn't return the desired output.

```
print(df.columns)

Index(['year', 'per capita income (US$)'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Could you share the basic format of the dataset ? (and the result you get)
In ML, the format and datatype making up the dataset is equally as important as the model itself. I cannot reproduce your error because I don't have the data, but my first instinct is that maybe your df['per capita income (US$)'] is in string format as opposed to double/float/int etc ...

Comment: Updated original question! Thank you for the prompt response!

Comment: df['year'] is an int. xxxx format while df['per capita income (USD$)'] is a float. xxxx.xxxx format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reshape your X to be a 2D array not 1D array. Fitting a model requires requires a 2D array. i.e (n_samples, n_features).

When you use `.reshape(-1,1)` it adds one dimension to the data.

```
X = df['year'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df['per capita income (US$)'].values
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X,y)
print(reg.predict([[2011]]))
```

Comment: This is the best solution explanation for the problem provided. Thank you!